# Aumentar tamaño de background en CSS

Tags: css, css3

Tengo una practica que estoy realizando y algunas letras dentro del background sobre salen un poco y quisiera saber como aumentar el background..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   .main .menu .platillo{

     font-family: 'MyriadProCondIt';

    margin-bottom: 30px;

    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 4px dotted rgb(242,143,0); 
    overflow: hidden;
 }

.main .menu .nombre{
background: rgb(242,143,0);
font-size: 20px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
float: left;
}


 <section class="menu">
      <div class="contenedor">
        <h3 class="titulo" id="platillos">Menú</h3>




        <div class="contenedor-menu">
        <div class="contenedor-menu2">

 <article>
       <p class="categoria">Chapatas</p>
         <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Chapata de atún</p>
           <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Ciapata, crema, chicharo, zanahoria, ejote, elote, papa, lechuga, jitomate y cebolla.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Chapata de pollo</p>
           <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Ciapata, mayonesa, chicharo, zanahoria, papa, lechuga, jitomate y cebolla morada.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Chapata de jamón</p>
           <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Ciapata, mayonesa, jamón, zanahoria, lechuga, jitomate y cebolla morada.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Chapata de quesos</p>
           <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Ciapata, mayonesa, queso crema, queso de cabra, queso manchego, queso oaxaca queso roquefort, zanahoria, lechuga, jitomate y cebolla morada.</p>
        </div>

         </article>   


 <article>

          <p class="categoria">Aguas </p>
         <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> AVELI</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Avena con limón.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Piñaco</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Piña coco.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre">  Ver té bien</p>
            <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Té verde con durazno.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Guanáranto</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Guanábana con amaranto.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Sandybuena</p>
         <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Sandia con hierbabuena.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Mentón</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Melón con menta</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Frextasis</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Agua mineral con frutos rojos.</p>
        </div>

    </article>
```

Comment: Aunque aparentemente es un problema sencillo de resolver, por favor agrega el código CSS (y tal vez una porción de HTML) relacionado.

Comment: Agrega el código como texto y no como imagen, gracias.

Comment: Solo da un poco de padding hacia los lados: `.main .menu .nombre { padding: 0 4px; }`.

Comment: gracias, estoy empezando en css y aun tengo confusiones... Me sirvió

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu tipo de fuente parece ser que con un poco de padding en el contenedor del nombre hacia izquierda y derecha debe ser suficiente:

```css
.main .menu .platillo {
  font-family: 'MyriadProCondIt';
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 4px dotted rgb(242,143,0); 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main .menu .nombre{
  background: rgb(242,143,0);
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<section class="menu">
      <div class="contenedor">
        <h3 class="titulo" id="platillos">Menú</h3>
        <div class="contenedor-menu">
        <div class="contenedor-menu2">

       <article>
       <p class="categoria">Chapatas</p>
         <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Chapata de atún</p>
           <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Ciapata, crema, chicharo, zanahoria, ejote, elote, papa, lechuga, jitomate y cebolla.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Chapata de pollo</p>
           <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Ciapata, mayonesa, chicharo, zanahoria, papa, lechuga, jitomate y cebolla morada.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Chapata de jamón</p>
           <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Ciapata, mayonesa, jamón, zanahoria, lechuga, jitomate y cebolla morada.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Chapata de quesos</p>
           <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Ciapata, mayonesa, queso crema, queso de cabra, queso manchego, queso oaxaca queso roquefort, zanahoria, lechuga, jitomate y cebolla morada.</p>
        </div>

         </article>   


 <article>

          <p class="categoria">Aguas </p>
         <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> AVELI</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Avena con limón.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Piñaco</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Piña coco.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre">  Ver té bien</p>
            <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Té verde con durazno.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Guanáranto</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Guanábana con amaranto.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Sandybuena</p>
         <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Sandia con hierbabuena.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Mentón</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Melón con menta</p>
        </div>


        <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Frextasis</p>
           <p class="precio">$19.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> -Agua mineral con frutos rojos.</p>
        </div>

    </article>
    </div>
```